# Swift: String to ints without special function

Tags: swift, date, expression

I'm searching for a build-in function for converting a string like
"01092030" (format "[[dd]hh]mmss") to four individual integers.

- dd => 01
- hh => 09
- mm => 20
- ss => 30

dd and hh are optional. If missing they should be 0. I could do it by by developing a special function, but I like to use something like a regular expression.

Comment: "I'm searching for a build-in function" Why? You don't want to write any code? "but I like to use something like a regular expression" Fine, but even if you could do that you'd still be writing code. What's the point of your "without special function" caveat?

Comment: Why would you use regular expressions for this? In any case, regex or not, that code belongs in its own function.

Comment: I meant, that I want to use a flexible definition, instead of a special implementation for this case. I have a function which checks each position of the string step by step. But the solution of matt looks more elegant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string contains date components you could alternatively use `NSDateFormatter`

```
let string  = "01092030"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let dayMissing = string.characters.count < 8
let hourMissing = string.characters.count < 6
dateFormatter.dateFormat = hourMissing ? "mmss" : dayMissing ? "HHmmss" : "ddHHmmss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)!
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
let second = components.second
let minute = components.minute
let hour = components.hour
let day = dayMissing ? 0 : components.day
```

Comment: Brilliant. Also matching my needs. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of your "build-in function" or "regular expression" requirements, but whatever...

```
let s = "092030" as NSString
let pattern = "\\d\\d"
let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = reg.matchesInString(s as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, s.length))
var result = matches.map {s.substringWithRange($0.range)}
while result.count < 4 {
    result.insert("0", atIndex: 0)
}
// result is: ["0", "09", "20", "30"]
```

I'm also a little unclear on your output requirements. On the one hand, you say you want four "individual integers". But "09" is not an integer; it's a string representing an integer. So it seems to me that you actually want strings. If so, then `result` is the desired result. If not, then you need one more step:

```
let result2 = result.map{Int($0)!}
// result2 is: [0, 9, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. 09 should indicate, that the 0 belongs to 9, which results in 9. The solution is excellent! Exactly what I searched for (including converting to int). Why is use of "pattern" not necessary (and this is a regular expression)?